# Why isn't this PHP date comparison behaving as I expect?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL database with a list of dates. I want to output all these dates, provided they occur after today, into a page. The dates are stored in the database in DATE format, as `Y-m-d`.

I've got the following code (excluding the query etc):

```
$dateToday = date('Y-m-d');

do{
    $dateCompare = new DateTime($row['date']);
    if ($dateCompare > $dateToday){
        echo '<p>'.$dateCompare -> format('Y-m-d').'</p>';
    } else {  
        echo '<p>FALSE</p>';
    }
}while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

But this just outputs all the dates, *including* one I have set in the past for testing purposes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The most obvious thing you're doing wrong is filtering a dataset from your DBMS at the application layer. This should be done at the DBMS layer. The next thing you're doing wrong is making assumptions about the format and type of the data - show us what the values are which are being compared.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the first two sentences...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$dateToday` is a string. `$dateCompare` is a `DateTime` object.

Comment: So I should use `strtotime()` to convert $dateToday?

Comment: Comparing apples and oranges is never a good idea, so make sure both are either apples or oranges. So ensure both are of type `DateTime`, or a unix timestamp, or a comparable string (in ISO8601 format). I'd go for the unix timestamp in most cases.

Comment: Thanks - just assigned `$dateToday` as `new DateTime('now');` and it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use strtotime() function.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp

Comment: Good luck with dates before Jan 1970.

Comment: yup, u cant use strtotime() for dates before jan 1970.

Answer (score 0):

Try and convert the date from myssql to a datetime object and output.

```
    $changetime = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

    ECHO $changetime->format('m/d/y h:i a');

// list of timezones http://us1.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
```

I actually use this to output all my MYSQL datetime data - allows me to convert to any timezone. Note, this will assume your datetime is in UTC - you should convert to your timezone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $time = strtotime($row['date']);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - $time) {
        echo '<p>'. date('Y-m-d', $time) . '</p>';
    } else {  
        echo '<p>FALSE</p>';
    }
}
```